# how to make node promise method sync?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, promise

I want to do some prepare work, and my other work should start after these is done, so I call these work by `Q.all`, but some work is async, this is what I want.

May be my code will make you understand me, in this simple example I want to do this:

1. call foo2 for item in array
2. in foo2, I wait `10 * a` ms(assume this to be some completed work), and change res.
3. I want to foo2 is running over then `console.log(res)`, this means all wait is over and all item is added to res. So in my example, res is change to 6.

Here is the code

```
var Q = require("q");
var res = 0;
function foo(a) {
  res += a;
}

function foo2(a) {
  // this is a simple simulation of my situation, this is not exactly what I am doing. In one word, change my method to sync is a little bit difficult
  return Q.delay(10 * a).then(function() {
    res += a;
  });
}

// Q.all([1, 2, 3].map(foo)).done(); // yes, this is what I want, this log 6

// however, because of some situation, my work is async function such as foo2 instead of sync method.
Q.all([1, 2, 3].map(function(a) {
  return foo2(a);
})).done();
console.log(res); // I want 6 instead of 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you **return** Q.delay(10*a) in your foo2 func?

Comment: I need to do some more complicated work in `foo2` with a, but I just give a simple example like `res += a`, I just want to point out that `foo2` is async!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: In foo2, you're not returning the promise. You should `return Q.delay(10*a)...`, which returns a promise.

Comment: Yeah, what is your question?

Comment: @Ludo I update the question

Comment: @jfriend00 question is updated

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing sync and async style of programming.

In this case, your `console.log` statement will be run before any promise had time to fulfill (before `res` was modified by them), as it it not inside a promise block.

See here how console.log will be run after promises have been resolved

```
var Q   = require("q"),
    res = 0;


function foo(a) { res += a; }

function foo2(a) {
  return Q
    .delay(10 * a)
    .then(function() { res += a; });
}

Q.all( [1, 2, 3].map(function(a) { return foo2(a); }) )
.then(function(){ console.log(res) })
.done();
```